# Fourier transform of the dipole dipole interaction

Tags: fourier-transform, dipole-moment

One can find on wikipedia the expression for the dipole-dipole interaction in the Fourier space: [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_dipole%E2%80%93dipole_interaction)

$$-\mu_0\frac{(\vec{m}_1\cdot\vec{q})(\vec{m}_2\cdot\vec{q})-|\vec{q}|^2(\vec{m}_1\cdot\vec{m}_2)}{|\vec{q}|^2}$$

I unfortunately cannot find any proper derivation of that expression in its most general case (where the dipoles are not necessarily aligned). Does any one of you know where could I find that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

We can do this with a bit of a trick. Let's do the reverse Fourier transform since that's a bit clearer. Notice that the expression can be written as
$$
\mu_0 m_1^\alpha \left(\delta_{\alpha\beta} - \hat{q}_\alpha \hat{q}_\beta\right) m_2^\beta
$$
with implicit summation over repeated indices, and hats denote normalized unit vectors. The quantity in parentheses is just the projector to the plane transverse to $\hat{q}$, and we wish to inverse Fourier transform it. Consider the second term first, where we have
$$
\int \frac{d^3q}{(2\pi)^3} \, \frac{q_\alpha}{q} \frac{q_\beta}{q} e^{i \vec{q}\cdot\vec{r}} = -\partial_\alpha \partial_\beta\int \frac{d^3q}{(2\pi)^3} \frac{e^{i\vec{q}\cdot\vec{r}}}{q^2}
$$
We can recognize the second integral as the Green's function for the Laplacian in three dimensions, or the integral can be done straightforwardly by changing to spherical coordinates,
$$
\frac{1}{(2\pi)^3}\int_0^\infty q^2 dq\int_{-1}^1 d(\cos\theta)\,\int_0^{2\pi} d\phi\,  \frac{e^{iqr \cos\theta}}{q^2} $$
$$
= 
\frac{1}{(2\pi)^2}\int_0^\infty dq \left[\frac{e^{iqr}-e^{-iqr}}{iqr}\right]$$
$$
= \frac{1}{2\pi^2 r}\int_0^\infty d(qr) \, \mathrm{sinc}(qr) = \frac{1}{4\pi \vert \vec{r}\vert}.
$$
So we have
$$
\int \frac{d^3q}{(2\pi)^3} \frac{q_\alpha}{q} \frac{q_\beta}{q} e^{i \vec{q}\cdot\vec{r}} = -\frac{1}{4\pi}\partial_\alpha \partial_\beta \frac{1}{\vert\vec{r}\vert}
$$
From here, we have
$$
\partial_\alpha \partial_\beta (r_\gamma r_\gamma)^{-1/2} =- \partial_\alpha \frac{r_\beta}{(r_\gamma r_\gamma)^{3/2}} 
= \frac{3 \hat{r}_\alpha \hat{r}_\beta - \delta_{\alpha\beta}}{r^3}
$$
The first term on the other hand gives a delta function, so in the end we obtain
$$
\mu_0 m_1^\alpha (\delta_{\alpha\beta} - \hat{q}_\alpha \hat{q}_\beta) m_2^\beta 
\longrightarrow
\mu_0\,\delta^3(\vec{r})\, \vec{m}_1(\vec{0}) \cdot \vec{m}_2(\vec{r}) + \frac{\mu_0}{4\pi} \frac{\delta_{\alpha\beta} - 3 \hat{r}_\alpha \hat{r}_\beta}{r^3} m_1^\alpha m_2^\beta
$$
where I have set the origin to the location of magnetic moment $\vec{m}_1$.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the derivation of this in JD Jackson: "THE NATURE OF INTRINSIC MAGNETIC DIPOLE MOMENTS", sections 3.1 and 3.2; see https://cds.cern.ch/record/118393/files/CERN-77-17.pdf